# Magento backend - make the price field readonly

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I want to make the price text field in magento backend readonly because I use another custom attributes to fix prices.

How can I do that ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Good lord, are you going for the "most number of questions asked in the shortest period of time" award?  :)

Comment: lol, I have began a new job as Magento developer and I have problems with it, I'm beginner with Magento and I don't want to loose my job! 
That's why I'm asking quite a lot of questions...

Help !

Comment: In that case, I suggest tagging your questions with `[magento]` as well as `[magento-1.4]`. You'll be noticed by more Magento users that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this would make attributes very silly, I don't believe that there is any simple mechanism by which to do this. One easy hack that you could use for this would be to add a JS file to that page which disables the price field specifically. Use the XML layout files for the default adminhtml package to add that JS file.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 6):

You need create an observer for `catalog_product_load_after` with the code like this:

```
$product->setLockedAttributes(array('price'));
```

And your product edit form will have readonly price field.