# Magento CE 1.6.2 - how to make customer attribute read-only?

Tags: magento

I've successfully added a new customer attribute (accountnumber), but I need to make this field read-only in the backend (it's populated from ERP software and needs to be visible but not editable through the Magento Admin Panel).

I've used an observer with the lockAttribute method to make catalog attributes (category/product) read-only in the Admin Panel, but there doesn't appear to be a corresponding method for customer attributes.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Check the below link, it may be helps you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793596/magento-backend-make-the-price-field-readonly

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Sankar. I had already seen that post, but unfortunately it doesn't help. The built-in methods available for locking catalog attributes don't exist for customer attributes.

Comment: What about creating an observer for  before save and reset that field with OrigData. See http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48711/what-is-the-difference-between-getorigdata-and-getdata

Answer (score 0):

You can set the *frontend_input* property as `label`

So it will be read-only in customer edit form.